# css: webkit-input-placeholder background color

Tags: css, background, webkit, placeholder

Try to set placeholder background color. It works fine until i try to increase input field height. In mozilla & ie placeholder background fills all space inside input. But in webkit background is set only for placeholder text height.

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/3zp36wL7/2/

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { 
    color: red;
    background: yellow;
}
```

You'll see yellow background in FF & IE, but in Chrome or Safari it looks terrible.

Is there any solution via css?

Comment: you could give the input a `line-height` equal to the height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `line-height` instead `height`;

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3zp36wL7/3/)

CSS

```
 ::-webkit-input-placeholder { 
    color: red;
    background: yellow;
 }
 :-moz-placeholder { 
   color: red;
   background: yellow;
 }
 ::-moz-placeholder { 
    color: red;
    background: yellow;
 }
 :-ms-input-placeholder { 
    color: red;
    background: yellow;
 }

 input {
    line-height: 50px;
 }
```

Comment: Thank You! This definetely solves one problem. But what if i want  not only increase line height, but move text to the left via padding. Just the same problem with blank space again. And in mozilla/IE no padding for placeholder. Any ideas? http://jsfiddle.net/3zp36wL7/5/ 

    input {
        line-height: 50px;
        padding-left: 10px;
    }

Comment: Only one solution which I found is this ugly hook http://jsfiddle.net/3zp36wL7/7/ ... but then cursor is covered by the placeholder so you have to add your own. However I think there is much better to solve this problem using a bit of JS/jQuery by check the value of the input, if value is empty than add background...